# Matplotlib: Plotting a dataframe with multiple subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date & Time  Amount   Count
Aug 2022    $10.50     53
            $14.00      1
            $3.50     416
            $35.00    186
Jul 2022    $14.00      1
            $3.50     844
            $35.00    307
Jun 2022    $14.00      1
            $3.50     797
            $35.00    323
```

I'm trying to use Matplotlib so that I can plot a bar graph (really a histogram) with the months/year as the xticks for the bigger plot, the amounts as xticks for the subplots, and the counts as the Y value.
Something like this:
[image]

The kicker is that the number of "Amount" values for each month can vary.

I'm stumped on how to do this one.

Comment: Seaborn’s barplots use matplotlib as is backend and achieve this easily.

Comment: is `Date & Time` the index? can you include the output of `df.to_dict()` instead?

Comment: Date & Time is not the index :(

and I will try out seaborn, having import issues with it atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this easily by installing Seaborn and adding the following code after the dataframe:

```
ndf = (DATAFRAME)
ndf = ndf.reset_index()
ploot = sns.barplot(x='Date & Time',y='Count',hue='Amount',data=ndf)
ploot.invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```